# Completely non-blocking HTTP request C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httprequest, nonblocking, asp.net-4.5

During my application's `Application_Start()` event I want to fire off a HTTP request to an address. I absolutely do not want any cost incurred by `Application_Start()` and for App Start to be delayed in any fashion. I do not care about the response from the request.

What is the most correct method for firing this request in a completely non-blocking fashion?

Comment: `Task.Run(() => callToAddressCode);` Although there will be a *slight* cost, since the server is still doing something extra.

Comment: Look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295479/async-await-blocking-ui-wp8 make separate request method call it on startup - make a fake task in it that just return quickly followed by your main requested.

Comment: You have to `await` the call to `client.GetAsync`, even though you aren't awaiting the `Task.Run`, any asynchronous operations within that method, should be awaited. Or, you can just add a `.Result` to the `GetAsync` since it being synchronous here shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: The `Task.Delay().Wait()` is forcing the first thread to wait 5 seconds, in that time, it allows the `GetAsync` to complete. You can uncomment the `responseTask.Result` line which will force the method to wait until the `GetAsync` completes or you can just do `client.GetAsync().Wait()` and there is no need to capture the `responseTask` or `Task.Delay`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://something.com/");
            var content = new StringContent("content");
            var result = httpClient.PostAsync("path/to/Service" , content);
            result.Wait();
        }
});
```

Comment: @ChrisMarisic I looked at this again, and yes you will need the call to result.Wait() in order for the call to PostAsync to complete. I've edited the code I posted. I was a little confused when I took this code from an old project of mine. I hope it is a little clearer now.

Comment: For clarity, without the `Wait()` the using statement scope is immediately exited invokes dispose on `httpClient` which cancels the in-flight http post

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend just firing the request asynchronously

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.PostAsJsonAsync("{url}",content)
}
```

for example will fire the request and continue

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WebClient.UploadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144240%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) Method for this purpose

This method does not block the calling thread.

It can throw

1. [ArgumentNullException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception(v=vs.100).aspx)
2. [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception(v=vs.100).aspx)

use it in this way

```
    var client = new WebClient();
    //remove comment from next line to execute some code after UploadString complete
    //client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(function name to execute when finish);
    var data = "data to send";
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "content type here");         
    client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.yourDomain.com"), data);
```